# Matlab not running large java programs

Tags: java, matlab

I am using matlab to access a java code, but it's not working when the code is not much resource intensive. The code runs when the called constructor of java is somewhat like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
                System.out.println("hello");
```

That is it prints "hello" thousand times in matlab but when code is like:

```
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
                System.out.println("hello");
```

It is supposed to print 10000 times, but in this case not even a single line is printing. But it is showing Busy status whereas in the task manager matlab is using zero percent of processor.

Why it is happening like that?

Comment: How do you call this? It is definately not valid matlab syntax. When I try this in matlab it works fine:  `for t=1:10000,java.lang.System.out.println('hello');end` Even after another 0. You say the code is like this, can you give exact code that actually reproduces the problem? -- Sidenote: I fixed a typo in your question as it may distract people.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I think you misunderstood, the code written above is in the constructor of the java class for which I intend to create an object. To call from matlab I use : javaObjectEDT('java_class'); in matlab.